# What-all does "pun" mean, really?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, puns

To my knowledge, a pun is a specific kind of wordplay hinged on a homophone/double-entendre (e.g., "What's black and white and re(a)d all over? A newspaper") or on multiple meanings of a word (e.g., "My car's not going to be ready until tomorrow; one of the mechanics sliced off the tips of his fingers, so now the shop's a little shorthanded").

Increasingly, though, I see people using "pun" as though it meant something like *Lookit! I just referred to the topic at hand, or used a word that has something to do with it, or used a word to mean what it actually means.* Examples from recent news articles (emphasis added; no relevant context omitted):

---

• It can be difficult for some players in the NFL to find their way, and such has been the case for Detroit’s Trinity Benson. His route has been unique, *no pun intended.* After all, Benson is a wide receiver. Undrafted out of East Central in 2019, Benson managed to stick around with the Denver Broncos for a couple of seasons.

•  I supported Matt Mowers in the past, partly because he worked for the President of the United States and partly because I thought he had the backs of the hard working NH residents. The “truth” is Matt Mowers is being exposed as a light weight politician who thinks he can hide behind Chris Christie, *no pun intended.*

• Ah yes, the golden *(no pun intended)* formula of kicking your opponents while they’re down. Or in this case, when they are down a man. After what’s becoming an accustomed slow start for the Canucks, Vancouver actually managed to direct the first three shots on net, and in close vicinity to goaltender Robin Lehner […]

• Scientifically, though, the concept [of near-death experiences] is pretty ill-defined. (…) That’s why now, scientists from a wide range of disciplines have published a new consensus statement regarding the study of death. Published in the Annals of the New York Academy of Sciences, the paper is the first-ever peer-reviewed statement on the scientific study of death, and is designed to “provide insights into potential mechanisms, ethical implications, and methodologic considerations for systematic investigation” and “identify issues and controversies” in the research area. The statement comes at a critical *(no pun intended)* time, as “death” in the 21st century isn’t the same as death even a hundred years ago.

• Getting perhaps the most obvious comparison out of the way, the billionaire-by-day/superhero-by-night arc is a direct parallel between Moon Knight and the Dark Knight. Although Oscar Issac's Marc Spector is a timid, mild-mannered museum employee, the comics portrayed the character as a successful billionaire who moonlights *(no pun intended)* as a deadly mercenary.

• Famously, "The Crown" switches its lead star after every two seasons, and it's kind of a kingmaker, *no pun intended.* Claire Foy, who played the Queen in the first couple of seasons, successfully transitioned to the movies.

• It is worth noting that Fresh was not actually Daisy Edgar-Jones’ first taste *(no pun intended, believe it or not)* of the horror genre. In fact, she also crossed “science fiction/fantasy” off of her bucket list at the same time when she was cast on Epix’s modernized series adaptation of H.G. Wells’ revolutionary novel, The War of the Worlds, in 2019.

• Cowell, who’s probably best known for horrifying viewers with his various reality TV series, didn’t get his showbiz start in Sony’s musical dungeon. No, he got it suffering on the set of Kubrick’s legendary horror movie The Shining, where he was apparently responsible for polishing Jack Nicholson’s axe *(no pun intended).*

• Gov. Brad Little vetoed HB723 which funded schools based on enrollment rather than attendance. Even though he said he is willing to look at the data in the upcoming year and would be willing to reinstate attendance funding, I have little faith *(no pun intended)* that this will amount to anything more than fluffy words to ease the apprehensions of voters. Given that this is an election year, I suspect that this is the true motivation behind Superintendent Ybarra’s and President Liebich’s optimism.

• Whether you’re wanting to hit mile-long bombs off the tee or need a new pair of FootJoy Tour 360 Golf Shoes, you can find all Masters-inspired merchandise right here. Oh, and if you’ve always dreamed about winning the Masters green jacket, you’ve struck gold – *no pun intended.*

---

I'm two shy of a dozen examples here, and their various other errors didn't irritate me as much as no pun in ten did!

Am I being unduly narrow and prescriptive? Or should I file this alongside "nukular" and "I could care less" and suchlike?

Comment: With all of these examples, you could have simply spent the time looking it up in some dictionaries. Short story: a pun is a play on words.

Comment: working shorthandedly,

Comment: Oh, sorry,* Dan Bron, I'm not seeing much of any wordplay in the examples I cited; perhaps I need to clean my glasses.                                                                                                                                     *in the Canadian sense

Comment: Several of those are very poor puns, if they are puns at all.  And of course when they say "no pun intended" they are often correct.

Comment: Perhaps the OP is asking whether *no pun intended* is being used  for *no humor/joke intended* rather than no (humorous) wordplay intended.

Comment: It seems pretty clear that you're really asking about the phrase *no pun intended* rather the word *pun*, in any other context.  This phrase does seem to have taken on a non-literal meaning and in those examples appears to mean *please excuse this bad wordplay*, or, as you point out, *look!  wordplay!*  I'd suggest reframing your question so that it explicitly asks about the history and current uses of *no pun intended*.  Even then, what would you hope to discover?  You're seeing how people use the phrase.  You can choose to be irritated or not.

Comment: For example, Chris Christie is a very *wide* person, so for a light-weight person hiding behind him would be easy.  But the "hide behind" and "light-weight" in the sentence are used figuratively.  (So it could be a pun, ha ha, but the writer claims that was not the resaon for using these figurative expressions.)

Comment: What does "What-all" mean?

Comment: I'll grant that you have many examples. Many examples. In addition to the Christie pun, you have *critical* meaning two things. along with *moonlights* and *kingmaker*.

Comment: There might be a legitimate question here, but first you would have to look up "pun" in dictionaries to see what it currently means, then disregard the legitimate puns (many seem to be plays on words), consider if there was any other reason for using the phrase "no pun intended", and after that process, try to ask a factual question about the remainder.

Answer (score 2):

"no pun intended" is usually used when a word/phrase has both a literal and figurative meaning, and either is a possible interpretation in the preceding sentence. This disclaimer indicates that the figurative meaning was intended, but acknowledges that one could force the literal meaning.

For example, "Matt Mowers ... hide behind Chris Christie" is being used to mean that Mowers's activities are overshadowed by Christie's. But Chris Christie is a physically large man, so Mowers could conceivably stand behind Christie to avoid being seen, which is the literal meaning of "hide behind".

So this is admitting that due to the dual meanings of the word, this *could* have been a pun, but it's not meant to be. But just to make things more confusing, sometimes it's used sarcastically when the speaker actually did intend it to be a funny juxtaposition of meanings. I think this usually happens when they didn't deliberately set out to create a pun, but they noticed it in their writing, and decided that it would be cute to keep it.

Comment: "(…) sometimes it's used sarcastically when the speaker actually did intend it to be a funny juxtaposition of meanings": Oy vey. The same excuse—I think it's a contrived one—is also used to prop up "I could care less". If any legitimate example of this type of alleged sarcasm exists, I think it's a rarity; all those I've seen or heard have actually been instances of dim wit.